# How to find power dissipation of bulbs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

The following circuit is connected in series and $240V$ power supply.

Bulb $A$ has $240V$, $100W$ rating.

Bulb $B$ has $240V$, $500W$ rating.

Calculate the power dissipated at bulb $A$ and $B$ respectively and determine which bulb is brighter.

If I'm correct, Bulb $A$ has $576$ $\Omega$ and Bulb B  $115.2$ $\Omega$  but I'm stuck here.

Comment: OK.  You've got the resistance of Bulb A.  Now, what is the resistance of Bulb B?  Once you have that, then what is the resistance of bulbs A and B _in series_?  If you had the series resistance, would you know how to calculate how much current flows in the 240V circuit?

Comment: Bulb B is 115.2ohm.

Comment: Current is 0.347A

Comment: Bulb A V=ir= 567ohm x 0.347A=200V

Bulb B V=ir=115.2ohm x 0.347A=40V

Comment: Hence,bulb A is brighter. Am I correct now?

Comment: power dissipation for bulb A is P=VI=200V x 0.347A= 69.4W

Comment: Unfortunayely the resistance of a light bulb depends strongly on the temperature so it is hard to make precise calculations.

Comment: Just connect them in parallel - it's a lot easier and actually reflects what non-retarded electricians do in real life.

Answer (score 1):

First, find resistance of each bulb. Use  R=V^2/P, where P is power rating.
Find series equivalent resistance. Add them.
Circuit current i is supply voltage divided by equivalent resistance.
Power dissipation P=i^2*R
Whichever bulb has higher power dissipation glows brighter.

Comment: Hi if  I used  P=i^2*R, wouldn't the power dissipation be higher than power rating?

Comment: No. Do it yourself and see. I did the sum. A dissipates 69.44W and B 13.88W